# Minimum and maximum of a box?

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic

Given the, width, height and depth of a box and its center point, how could I find the minimum, x, y, and z coordinate and the maximum x, y and z coordinate without bruteforcing through each vertex? its an AABB box.

Thanks

```
from a top view
---------------
|              |
|              |
|      c       |
|              |
|--------------|
```

Comment: Are the axes of the box parallel to the x, y and z axis?

Comment: If you assume that one end of the box is at the origin of a 3D coordinate system you'd know the maximum vertex to be (w, h, d) and the minimum to be (0, 0, 0). You would also know the center's co-ords. Now, transform the center from it's current position to the given position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
(xmin, ymin, zmin) = (xcentre, ycentre, zcentre) - (width, height, depth) / 2
(xmax, ymax, zmax) = (xcentre, ycentre, zcentre) + (width, height, depth) / 2
```

or in full:

```
xmin = xcentre - width / 2
xmax = xcentre + width / 2
ymin = ycentre - height / 2
...
```

Comment: Not if the box is not aligned to all three axes.